# Write single value on firebase database without deleting the existing ones

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'am trying to add a single value my database without deleting the existing ones because I need them all. The structure is something like that /user/fav_post/{post_id_1,post_id_2,...}. The "fav_post" initially is empty and as the time goes by the user adds more fav_posts.

One way that solves this problem is downloading all favorite posts, putting them in a HashMap, add the new post and the push them to the database but this does not seem very optimal.

So what I am trying to achieve is to have all the favorite posts and to display them to the user.

```
 mDatabase.child("USERS")
       .child(currentUser.getUid())
       .child("favorites")
       .setValue(postID);
```

Edit: The end result should be like

Ther end result I want to be like that 
root

```
-User

--FavPosts

---postID1(String)
```

And when the user favorites another post the result should be like that:

```
root
-User

--FavPosts

---postID1(String)

---postID2(String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a *set*: an unordered collection of unique values. In the Firebase Database you'd store the post Id as a key and (since Firebase doesn't allow you to store a key without a value) `true` as the value.

So:

```
root: {
  User: {
    FavPosts: {
      postID1: true,
      postID2: true
    }
  }
}
```

You'd set these values with:

```
 mDatabase.child("USERS")
       .child(currentUser.getUid())
       .child("favorites")
       .child(postID) 
       .setValue(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

setValue() will overwrite the entire contents of the location.  If you want to just add or update child values, use [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) instead.

Comment: The updateChildren method needs a Map(key,value) and I just want to push a value not a key-value pair.

Comment: A "push" operation always creates new data using a generated unique key.  So now I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish.  Could you be more specific in your question exactly what you want to see happen in your database?